# How to include non-standard CSS @-rules in Sass?

Tags: css, sass, princexml

I'm trying to add some non-standard CSS @-rules from [Prince XML](https://www.princexml.com/doc/9.0/page-selectors/) in my Sass workflow, but can't find a way to do so.

Desired CSS output:

```
@page {
  @bottom { ... };
  ...
}
```

This gives an *Unclosed block* error when included in Sass as such.

The following code compiles, but just ignores the entire block in the CSS output:

```
#{'@'}page {
  #{'@'}bottom { ... };
  ...
}
```

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: how do you compile? In sassmeister there are no errors: http://www.sassmeister.com/gist/410fa40055594462ab05df366136f7c3

Comment: I'm using gulp within Laravel-elixir (v1 in a legacy project). Seems I might have to look to another compiler, thanks for pointing me in the right direction!